# PHP: Add a method to a php file

Tags: php

I want to edit a php file with PHP code so that a class that looks like this:

```
 class Foo{
    public function bar(){
    }
 }
```

can look like this:

```
 class Foo{
    public function bar(){
    }   
    public function barbar(){
    }
 }
```

My problem with fopen be that I can't detect wheter its in the class or not

Is this possible?

are there downsites, recommodations derecommodations? anything

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: You can't safely do that without parsing the entire PHP script properly. What is the application of that anyway? It looks like you are trying the wrong approach for something.

Comment: You want to literally modify the class? Why not extend the class and add the method you want. But if I'm misunderstanding, and you need to do this on the fly, some metaprogramming is doable (if actually necessary?) Start with [Reflection](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.construct.php)

Comment: I am deveveloping a admin interface to add methods to controllers, having a view requires to have a method in a class, its all very basic and I thought I could maybe do it like this

Comment: If you need to call methods which don't actually exist to render views, that's the purpose of [the `__call()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) magic method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a POG. Add a comment in the class Foo, like this:

```
class Foo{
    public function bar(){
    }

    // something
}
```

After, you can do it:

```
$comment = '// something';
$method = 'public function barbar(){}';

str_replace($comment, $method . $comment, $file);
```

So, your file will be like this:

```
class Foo{
    public function bar(){
    }   
    public function barbar(){
    }

    // something
}
```